# How to create separate .css file in webpack in dev mode? Not virtually emited, but built in a project directory

Tags: css, webpack, path

The problem is, that I have configured my virtualhosts so the website I need to work on is not under localhost:8080.

Right now my webpack puts my styles into .html file between `<style></style>` and only for production it creates a file in my project dir.
But I'd need to have a separate file created in dev mode. Not "emited" under http://localhost:8080, because this way all my paths in .css file point to "localhost:8080/assets/..."

When I put this into my project:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

It works, but the images paths are broken, as browser loads them from "localhost:8080/assets..." not from "myproject.domain/assets..."

So I've figured out that creating a style.css file in my directory would do the job, but this I can achieve only in production mode, then my style is generated... any idea how to achieve this in development? Or some workaround?

I beliefe the question is general enough I don't need to put my code. I use only:
MiniCssExtractPlugin / style-loader, css-loader, sass-loader.

Comment: it will be part of your webpack config is your style in critical in your dev config?  Usually the critical styles get output into style tags (I think - quite new to webpack myself)

Comment: @Pete You mean critical plugin, but this puts styles inline so it does exactly oposite what I need as far as I understand

Comment: Yeah - I thought you said in dev they were inline in the head - anything I include in my `entry: { critical: [  'sass/critical.scss',  ],` gets inlined into my header

Comment: @Pete this plugin I don't use. So how do you use your webpack with the styles? When developing, on "watch mode" your styles get put into html, or you somehow use this emited style linking them from path: "localhost:8080/emited_style.css"?

Comment: hmmm I guess it must be the `webpacks-merge` plugin we use we just define our main entry point and anything we don't want in the header styles gets put in there.  This is my config: http://jsfiddle.net/j5Lv4ds0/

Comment: @Pete ok, I see. Your config file doesn't include webpacks-merge, and I beliefe you talk about the production mode. I need to have localy saved .css file while dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use /your_img_path with out localhost if the img is under your root directory.